# How to grab the :id from URLs using Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am currently working on Cypress tests and encountered an issue to which I cannot find the answer. Hopefully someone can help.

So, in ReactJs I have the following component that I want to test:

```
<Link
  to={`/example/${exampleId}/subexample/create`}
  className={classes.linkIcon}
  title="Create subexample"
  data-test="new-subexample"
>
```

To test this piece, in Cypress I am first creating a new `example` and that works fine, but then to test the `subexample` gives me problems because `data-test="new-subexample"` is not doing what I am expecting (i.e. to click on the `/example/:exampleId/subexample/create` link). Here is some code:

```
    cy.get("[data-test=new-subexample]").click()
    const subexample = faker.lorem.paragraph().substring(0, 200);

    ......
    cy.get('[data-test="submit-subexample"]').click();
    cy.get(".toast--success").should("be.visible");
  });
```

Did anyone encountered this before and how did you manage to click on the links where the id is always changing?

Also, maybe one approach would be to grab the `:exampleId` after `example` has been created (also via Cypress), but I cannot find anywhere how to get the element from the URL using Cypress.

Thanks in advance.

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tonUc.png)

UPDATE: The problem was the redirect which took some time and never completed in time for the test to pass. I added a wait (using cy.wait()) time before the redirect and now the test passed.

Comment: The screenshot of the error doesn't seem related to the elements mentioned in your code.

Comment: very good you noticed that, will update my question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To test the URL after redirect, you can use [`cy.url`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url.html#Assert-the-URL-is-http-localhost-8000-users-1-edit).

```
cy.url().should('include', `/example/${exampleId}/subexample/create`);
```